# How to convert a string to its Base-10 representation?

Tags: python, string, base-conversion

Is there any python module that would help me to convert a string into a 64-bit integer?
(the maximum length of this string is 8 chars, so it should fit in a long).

I would like to avoid having to write my own method.

Example:

```
Input String   Hex          result (Base-10 Integer)
'Y'            59           89
'YZ'           59 5a        22874
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a job for [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html):

```
>>> s = 'YZ'
>>> struct.unpack('>Q', '\x00' * (8 - len(s)) + s)
(22874,)
```

Or a bit trickier:

```
>>> int(s.encode('hex'), 16)
22874
```

Comment: Great! Is there an easy way to perform the opposite conversion, i.e. get the string 'YZ' from the integer 22874?

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri Sure - try `struct.pack('>H', 22874)`.

Comment: will this return the same number every time across versions and platforms (unlike say `hash(s)`) ?

Comment: @Anentropic yes

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a built-in method to do this, but it's easy enough to cook up:

```
>>> int("".join([hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in "YZ"]), 16)
22874
```

This goes via base 16 which can of course be optimized out. I'll leave that "as an exercise".

Comment: take a look at 'hex' encoding :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
sum(ord(c) << i*8 for i, c in enumerate(mystr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: a*256+b, map(ord,'YZ'), 0)
22874
```