# Is there a way to convert a string to a base 10 number for encryption?

Tags: javascript

Note: I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716796/how-to-convert-a-string-to-its-base-10-representation), but it is in python.

---

I've been trying to think of an algorithm or native method for this, and I'm stumped.

This is what I have so far:

```
encode=function(n,f){
    return (n).toString(f)
}
decode=function(s,f){
    return parseInt(s,f)
}
```

Basically, I need a way to convert a string, like `'Hello World!'` to a base 10 (hexadecimal will work as well) number, like `14438792758793754875`, and I am wondering if there's a proper way to do it before I possibly waste my time with something like:

```
str='Hello World'
returnString=''
for(var i in str){
    returnString+=(
        str[i]=='A'?'0'
        :str[i]=='B'?'1'
        etc...
    )
}
```

Not only would that be very time consuming, but I have no idea how I would possibly convert it back, as once I get into numbers like `11` for `L`, a for loop wouldn't do, and would return `BB`.

The reason I am asking this is because I plan to use it in the future for more efficient and secure, encrypted storage. for example, something like:

```
//save
numstr=encodeToNumber(inputElement.value)
b36str=encode(numstr,36)
storage['items'].push(b36str)
localStorage['App Data']=JSON.stringify(storage)

//load
if(localStorage['App Data']){
    storage=JSON.parse(localStorage['App Data'])
}else{
    storage={
        items:[],
        config:{
            etc
        }
    }
}
//Assuming storage.items looks like this: ['rgie', 'zyy', '2il7']
for(i in storage['items']){
    b36str=storage['items']//rgie, zyy, 2il7
    numstr=decode(b36str,36)//1281110, 46618, 117403
    container.innerHTML+='<hr>'+decodeFromNumber(numstr)//Milk, Eggs, Bread
}

//Output
Milk
Eggs
Bread
```

I actually did spend several minutes manually encrypting 'Milk', 'Eggs', and 'Bread' to their base36 counterparts so it could be accurate.

---

Update: `Aadit M Shaw` gave a function that produces hexadecimal strings from strings, and I reverse engineered it to my needs and got this:

```
en=function(s){
    var s2d=function(s){
        s=s.replace(/ /g,'+').replace(/!/g,'.')
        var n=[]
        for(var i in s){
            n.push(s.charCodeAt(i))
        }
        return n
    }
    var arr=s2d(s)
    var s2=''
    for (var i in arr){
        s2+=arr[i].toString(36)
    }
    return s2
}
de=function(s){
    var arr=s.split(/(..)/)
    var arr2=[]
    var s2=''
    for(var i in arr){
        if(arr[i]){
            arr2.push(parseInt(arr[i],36))
        }
    }
    for(var i in arr2){
        s2+=String.fromCharCode(arr2[i])
    }
    return s2.replace(/\+/g,' ')
}
```

While the encoded string is larger than I would have liked, it could be useful for protecting cookies from being hacked or something.

For example, using the example I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/meA7f/), I made this message `21173b2x3030172t2p38173d333936172u2p2r2t` as well as this `ЎǄ̺ǦǄ̌`. And if you manage to decode the second one, then decode this too `ʒ̴ͻϮ`

This isn't very practical, though, so I'll probably end up using the library `Ragnarokkr` linked me to.

Thank you all for the responses!

Comment: Define "encrypted": Why not just encrypt it?

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're asking why I don't just use the `encode` method I provided, it's because it only accepts base 10 integers.

Comment: If you want something secure, something trivial like this is useless. I'm asking why don't you just use actual encryption instead of trying to implement something yourself? I don't understand your comment regarding "base 10 integers", you said it could be hex--which is it?

Comment: if you need **true** encryption, I think [this library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) could be really useful. It supports hash and encryption/decryption algorithms as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton because I haven't found any native method, and I'm trying to do this with only JavaScript. And I accept hexadecimal because I could easily just decode that to decimal and the re encode to base 36

Comment: @Ragnarokkr I'll definitely give that a look

Comment: @B1KMusic There isn't native encryption, but there are many encryption libraries.

Comment: If the concern is data traveling through the internet, there is a well known way to encrypt things. It is called ssl/tls. You can send data through it just like with http, but it will get encrypted before it is sent. Most people call it https.

Comment: @Dave I'm fine with using a library.

Comment: I guess, http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ is what you need. It is easy-to-use and it contains several algorithms. So, for you algorithm AES or converting input string to hex string can be appropriate

Comment: @Patrick Yes I am fond of Transport Layer Security, but my main purpose for this is the design of webapps which use localStorage. Since localStorage has that 5 MB limit, base 36 encoding could increase the amount of data that can be saved. This was my initial reason for experimenting with this.

Comment: @Ragnarokkr If you had answered with that link I would have given you the `accepted answer`. Thanks alot! It's a great library.

Comment: @B1KMusic thanks. I'm happy to know that it was helpful to you ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
function encode(string) {
    var number = "0x";
    var length = string.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        number += string.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    return number;
}
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hGKAg/2/

Decoding is just as simple:

```
function decode(number) {
    var string = "";
    number = number.slice(2);
    var length = number.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length;) {
        var code = number.slice(i, i += 2);
        string += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(code, 16));
    }
    return string;
}
```

Try the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hGKAg/3/

Comment: I can't really use `8.752161808888254e+25` (what I got from entering `Hello World`)

Comment: @B1KMusic - I updated the answer. Since you don't mind hexadecimal, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Umm, I still got `8.752161808888254e+25` when I converted the hex string back to decimal.

Comment: @B1KMusic - The problem is that JavaScript numbers are double precision floating point values. That's why very large values get converted to exponential form.

Comment: @B1KMusic - Is it essential for you to convert the string into a number? If not then IMHO this is all you need.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I __can__ use this, because when I tried to convert the number to base 36 I got `azw5bz2xp57qck4sw`. But when I decoded it back I got "ello X". So there's still a problem...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22783/discussion-between-b1kmusic-and-aadit-m-shah)

Comment: From the method you used, `String.prototype.charCodeAt()`, I was able to engineer my own method, and successfully translated `Hello` to `202t303033` and back. So I'm upvoting your answer. Thanks

Comment: This is a  good answer, but the base here is `16`. The OP questions was for a base 10.

Comment: @HolgerLudvigsen The OP mentioned in his question that _“hexadecimal will work as well”_.

Answer (score 1):

While I've never used this before, a friend of mine has given this library a good review. Apparently, you can encode strings using any Base standard with this library:

[Nibbler.js](http://www.tumuski.com/2010/04/nibbler/)